# Making an app for Ubuntu Software Centre

Tags: software-center, application-development, desktop-environments

I would love to make apps and publish them on the Ubuntu Software Centre. After following the instructions on the developer centre, I built an app and published it. Now I have realised I have built an app for Ubuntu touch. There doesn't seem to be an SDK for making Ubuntu desktop apps. Is there one? Where can I find simple instructions to make and upload an ubuntu desktop app? Thanks.

Comment: Is quickly official? Is it maintained by canocial/ubuntu?

Comment: Nothing in this site is directly maintained by Canonical. Please, refer to [this post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5444/169736) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu SDK is called [Quickly.](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quickly/)  It does run on the command line, but it's still easy to use.  [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg) is a good video tutorial to get started.

Comment: Actually, the Ubuntu SDK is the new SDK for writing applications in QML and currently focusing on Ubuntu Touch. Quickly is the old tool for creating Ubuntu apps, but is not the Ubuntu SDK.

Comment: Is quickly official? Is it maintained by canocial/ubuntu?